# Merging home directories

Tags: home-directory

Here's the thing. I did a fresh install of 11.10. I created a separate partition for /home and another for /. I then installed 11.04 on the / partition. Now I still have the /home on the separate partition and the home dir that came with 11.04. How do I merge the two or replace the 11.04 home directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command:

```
sudo rsync -vaEW /path/to/old/home /path/to/new/home
```

This will effectively sync the two directories.

Comment: No problem. Pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

The rsync tool can be useful in this case. It can copy remotely or locally. I used it to copy filed from my encrypted home directory to my current home directory.

```
$ rsync options source destination
```

where source represents a directory/file/network path, destination represents a network path/directory. The options section includes several options which are used to control its behavior and allow specificity with regards to the files to be copied. They include but not limited to `-avzh`,`avZ`,`v`, `q` etc. [Click here](https://linuxhint.com/rsync_copy_files_ubuntu/) Hope it helps.